# How to stop R shiny session or R script without stack trace?

Tags: r, shiny

I have complex code and I have two withCallingHandlers that handle errors. and I want to call `stop()` to stop R or shiny session but I have a long stacktrace. I've tried:

```
invokeRestart("abort")
```

but then I've got error:

```
Error in execCallbacks(timeoutSecs, all, loop$id) : 
Calls: <Anonymous> ... ..stacktracefloor.. -> serviceApp -> service -> run_now -> execCallbacks
Execution halted
```

is it possible to stop R without stack trace? Note that I can't call `quit()`, since this will stop all shiny sessions.

Comment: I’m assuming you mean `quit`, not `exit`? And what’s the issue with having a stack trace?

Comment: @KonradRudolph the logs are saved in ELK I don't want any additional errors if I'm the one that triggers the error. Note that I have 3 screens of function calls from shiny. I only want stack traces for cases when my code is throwing an error because there is a bug in the code, not when I call stop() manually. I should get just `"Execution halted"`.

Comment: Does `quit()` work?

Comment: @HongOoi quit as I've said end R process.